# How to combine 2 imagemagick commands together

Tags: php, imagemagick

I got 2 seprate Imagemagick commands (resize and crop circle). Is it possible to combine both commands into single PHP exec.

```
exec('convert original.jpg -resize x100 -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage thumbnail.jpg');
exec('convert -size 100x100 xc:none -fill thumbnail.jpg -draw "circle 50,50 50,0" circle.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

start a shell in your exec command and supply the executables as parameters to the shell, separated by ';'

e.g. bash -c "ls /tmp/; echo bla"

Comment: Won't help the OP: He's asking whether he can combine two ImageMagick operations into one call.

Comment: No no read carefully, he is asking whether it is possible to combine the two commands in one php exec.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but have you tried simply literally combining them?

```
exec('convert original.jpg -resize x100 -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage
     xc:none -draw "circle 50,50 50,0" circle.png');
```

(line break added for clarity)

The only thing I'm unsure about is the `xc:none` as I don't know what that does. Other than that, it should be easy to combine these.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can chain them with the `&&` operand:

```
exec('convert original.jpg -resize x100 -gravity center -crop 100x100+0+0 +repage thumbnail.jpg && convert -size 100x100 xc:none -fill thumbnail.jpg -draw "circle 50,50 50,0" circle.png');
```

Even though that's two calls to `convert`, it's a single PHP exec call.

Regards